# How I can deploy superset on K8s using helm chart in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, runtime-error, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I try to deploy with this .yml

```yaml
variables:
CHART_REPOSITORY: '' # URL de repositorio de Charts de Helm.
CHART_NAME: '' # Nombre del chart en el repositorio

CHART_VERSION: '' # Versión exacta del chart, si no se especifica, se usa la más reciente
HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS: '' # Argumentos arbitrarios adicionales añadidos al comando helm upgrade. Ref https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#options

RELEASE_NAME: $CHART_NAME
 
HELM_INSTALL_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/helm-install-image/releases/3.5.3-kube-1.16.15-alpine-3.12
 
ENVIRONMENT_NAME: production

VALUES_FILE: 'values.y*ml'

stages:
deploy

deploy:
stage: deploy
only:
master
main
image: $HELM_INSTALL_IMAGE
environment:
name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
script:
values_path=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$VALUES_FILE" | head -n1)
    - |
helm upgrade "$RELEASE_NAME" "$CHART_NAME" \
        --namespace "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" \
        ${CHART_REPOSITORY:+--repo $CHART_REPOSITORY} \
        ${CHART_VERSION:+--version $CHART_VERSION} \
        ${values_path:+-f $values_path} \
        --install \
        --create-namespace \
        --wait \
        --wait-for-jobs \
        $HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS
```

This is the result

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:b95732bb43121fede653c4095be0b47d06555480ea4511ab26094b9fda503266 for     registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/helm-install-image/releases/3.5.3-kube-1.16.15-alpine-   3.12 with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/helm-install-image/releases/3.5.3-kube-  1.16.15-alpine-3.12@sha256:5670adc971e8698b1cafb35110277993f6c35a80eb10653c8edb52918b282882 ...
export RANCHER_APP_EXTRA_ARGS="\ # collapsed multi-line command
values_path=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$VALUES_FILE" | head -n1)
helm upgrade "$RELEASE_NAME" "$CHART_NAME" \ # collapsed multi-line command
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location:   /builds/dgti/eaf/superset-dss.tmp/KUBECONFIG
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /builds/dgti/eaf/superset-dss.tmp/KUBECONFIG
Error: release name is invalid: `your text`
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
0:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I see:

> ```
> Error: release name is invalid: `your text`
> ```

That should mean the variable `RELEASE_NAME` is not being set correctly.
From your provided YAML, `RELEASE_NAME` is assigned as `$CHART_NAME` which in turn is also an empty string in your initial `variables` section.

```yaml
variables:
CHART_NAME: '' # Nombre del chart en el repositorio
...
RELEASE_NAME: $CHART_NAME
```

You need to specify the value of `CHART_NAME` correctly. In this case, it should be the name of the Helm chart for Superset which you want to deploy on Kubernetes.

For example, if you have a helm chart for Superset in your helm repository, the `CHART_NAME` should be the name of that chart. And `CHART_REPOSITORY` should be the URL of the helm repository where your Superset chart is located.

That would be:

```yaml
variables:
CHART_REPOSITORY: 'https://helm-repo-url/' # URL de repositorio de Charts de Helm.
CHART_NAME: 'superset' # Nombre del chart en el repositorio
CHART_VERSION: '1.0.0' # Versión exacta del chart, si no se especifica, se usa la más reciente
HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS: '' # Argumentos arbitrarios adicionales añadidos al comando helm upgrade. Ref https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#options
RELEASE_NAME: $CHART_NAME
HELM_INSTALL_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/helm-install-image/releases/3.5.3-kube-1.16.15-alpine-3.12
ENVIRONMENT_NAME: production
VALUES_FILE: 'values.y*ml'
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
    - main
  image: $HELM_INSTALL_IMAGE
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  script:
    - |
      values_path=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$VALUES_FILE" | head -n1)
      helm upgrade "$RELEASE_NAME" "$CHART_NAME" \
          --namespace "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" \
          ${CHART_REPOSITORY:+--repo $CHART_REPOSITORY} \
          ${CHART_VERSION:+--version $CHART_VERSION} \
          ${values_path:+-f $values_path} \
          --install \
          --create-namespace \
          --wait \
          --wait-for-jobs \
          $HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS
```

You would need to replace `'https://helm-repo-url/'` with the actual URL of your Helm repository and `superset` with the actual Helm chart name of Superset.
And make sure the `KUBE_NAMESPACE` where you want to deploy the application is defined somewhere in your CI/CD pipeline. The `values.y*ml` should be the path to your Superset Helm chart's values file that you wish to use for configuration.

That supposes the Kubernetes permissions are set up in order to allow GitLab to deploy to your specified namespace. This typically involves creating a service account and role with appropriate permissions, then using the generated kubeconfig for your GitLab CI/CD pipeline.
See for more "[Using GitLab CI/CD with a Kubernetes cluster / Authorize the agent to access your projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#authorize-the-agent-to-access-your-projects)"